# Подключил appoodeil в свое приложение и теперь вылазит такая ошибка! Кто знает что это и как решить?

Tags: java, android, gradle

**Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.behealthroom1.user"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    repositories {

        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
        implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите **android-support-v7-recyclerview-23.1.1.jar** из папки **app/libs/** . Мне это помогло.

Дополнительно посмотрите, пожалуйста, пример build.gradle:
https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-android-demo/blob/master/app/build.gradle